# Juggling Job Offers and Interviews

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I’m currently working as a developer at Company A. For reasons I won’t delve into here, I’m looking to leave my current position and find a new place to work. I started sending out resumes a couple of months ago, and have been actively interviewing for the past several weeks.

I’ve been through multiple interviews with Company B for a developer position, and I think we’re a pretty great fit for each other. I don’t have a solid offer yet, but I’ve been assured by the recruiter that an offer is coming (possibly once the holidays are over). We’ve discussed my salary range and they’re on board with that.

At the same time, I’m going through the interview process with Company C. This company also seems like a good fit, and has a couple of advantages over Company B. However, due to the Christmas/New Year holidays, I won’t be able to schedule the next interview with them until a week or two into January.

Assuming that Company B comes through with an offer like we discussed in the next few days, how can I best handle the interview process at Company C? I’d prefer to wait to give B an answer until I know more from Company C, and find out, after our next interview, if a second offer might be forthcoming. However, I definitely don’t want things to fall through with B while I’m waiting on C to get back from the holidays.

How long can I reasonably expect Company B to wait to get an answer from me? And how can I best handle this so that I don’t inadvertently burn any bridges?

Answer (score 3):

**This will happen every time you get a new job**

Sometimes great companies have terrible hiring practices.  Sometimes the job you want the most is your very last interview.  You have to decide between the sure thing and the possibility of a better thing.

In general, companies will wait about 2 weeks (maybe more since holidays are right around the corner).  Sometimes a time limit is written in the employment contract, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 1):

If B is a great fit as you stated then you should accept their offer if it comes your way.  At that point you would tell C that you are no longer available for the interview and thank them for their interest.  This should not burn any bridges, as they will understand that you are actively looking for a job and likely have multiple options.